# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error- WordPress related

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have made a WordPress site(using a theme called Ask Me) and trying a plugin(called Super Socialezer) for social login through Facebook. But I can't login using Facebook. The error shown is as follows:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I can't figure out what to do. Upon reading several similar queries, I figured it has something to do with `.htaccess` file, but I can't figure out any further. I am new at programming.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Reset your .htaccess to the WP default (make a backup of your current one), and test it then - if it doesn’t work then, I think this is something you should contact the plugin author about. (We are not here to give support for 3rd-party scripts, and that you will be able to solve it yourself on your current level sounds rather doubtful as well.)